# MySQL slow query with SELECT/ORDER BY on one table with WHERE on another, LIMIT results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query the top N rows from a couple of tables.  The WHERE clause refers to a list of columns in one table, whereas the ORDER BY clause refers to columns in the other.  It looks like MySQL is choosing the table involved in my WHERE clause for its first pass of filtering (which doesn't filter much) whereas it's the ORDER BY that affects the rows returned once I apply the LIMIT.  If I force MySQL to use a covering index for the ORDER BY, the query returns immediately with the desired rows.  Unfortunately I can't pass index hints to MySQL through JPA, and rewriting everything using native queries would be a substantial amount of work.  Here's an illustrative example:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(255),
    last_name VARCHAR(255)
) engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE membership (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE employee (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    membership_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(15),
    enabled BIT NOT NULL,
    person_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES person ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_employee_membership_id FOREIGN KEY ( membership_id ) REFERENCES membership ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_employee_person_id FOREIGN KEY ( person_id ) REFERENCES person ( id )
) engine=InnoDB;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uk_employee_person_id ON employee ( person_id );

CREATE INDEX idx_person_first_name_last_name ON person ( first_name, last_name );
```

I wrote a script to output a bunch of INSERT statements to populate the tables with 200'000 rows:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
echo "INSERT INTO membership ( id, name ) VALUES ( 1, 'Default Membership' );"
for seq in {1..200000}; do
    echo "INSERT INTO person ( id, first_name, last_name ) VALUES ( $seq, 'firstName$seq', 'lastName$seq' );"
    echo "INSERT INTO employee ( id, membership_id, type, enabled, person_id ) VALUES ( $seq, 1, 'INDIVIDUAL', 1, $seq );"
done
```

My first attempt:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM person p INNER JOIN employee e ON p.id = e.person_id
WHERE e.membership_id = 1 AND type = 'INDIVIDUAL' AND enabled = 1
ORDER BY p.first_name ASC, p.last_name ASC, p.id ASC
LIMIT 100;
-- 100 rows in set (1.43 sec)
```

and the EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                   | key                       | key_len | ref                | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | NULL       | ref    | uk_employee_person_id,fk_employee_membership_id | fk_employee_membership_id | 4       | const              | 99814 |     5.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                         | PRIMARY                   | 4       | qsuite.e.person_id |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Now I force MySQL to use the ( first_name, last_name ) index on person:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM person p USE INDEX ( idx_person_first_name_last_name )
    INNER JOIN employee e ON p.id = e.person_id
WHERE e.membership_id = 1 AND type = 'INDIVIDUAL' AND enabled = 1
ORDER BY p.first_name ASC, p.last_name ASC, p.id ASC
LIMIT 100;
-- 100 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It returns instantly.  And the explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                   | key                             | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | index  | NULL                                            | idx_person_first_name_last_name | 2046    | NULL        |  100 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | NULL       | eq_ref | uk_employee_person_id,fk_employee_membership_id | uk_employee_person_id           | 4       | qsuite.p.id |    1 |     5.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Note the WHERE clause in the example doesn't end up actually filtering any rows.  This is largely representative of the data I have and the bulk of queries against this table.  Is there a way to coax MySQL into using that index or some not-quite-destructive way of restructuring this to improve the performance?

Thanks.

Edit: I dropped the original covering index and added one to each of the tables:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_person_id_first_name_last_name ON person ( id, first_name, last_name );
CREATE INDEX idx_employee_etc ON employee ( membership_id, type, enabled, person_id );
```

It seems to speed it up a little, but MySQL still insists on running through the employee table first:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                              | key              | key_len | ref                | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | NULL       | ref    | uk_employee_person_id,idx_employee_etc     | idx_employee_etc | 68      | const,const,const  | 97311 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_person_id_first_name_last_name | PRIMARY          | 4       | qsuite.e.person_id |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: "I'm trying to query the top N rows from a couple of tables."  That's nice.  You don't seem to explain what you are really trying to do.  How are you defining "top"?  What is "N"?   What problem do you have?

Comment: What do you mean by "not-quite-destructive"? Is `FORCE INDEX`  or `STRIGHT_JOIN` too destructive?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's slow, as I mentioned in the subject, and the N is 100, in the limit, i.e. I want the first 100 results.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Really I just meant without having to completely reorganize the way the data is stored; using FORCE INDEX or STRAIGHT_JOIN requires using native SQL (note I mentioned I'm using JPA so I can't use vendor extensions like index hints or alternative join clauses).

Comment: What about subqueries? Can you use them?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I can use subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I would have your second index on the person table to be on `(id, first_name, last_name)` and get rid of the second index unless you will really be querying by a person's first name as the primary basis.

For the employee table, have an index on `(membership_id, type, enabled, person_id)`

Having the proper index on employee table will help get all qualifying records back.  Having the person's name and ID info in the index prevents the engine from going to the raw data pages to extract the columns from for final ordering / limit

```
SELECT 
        e.*
    FROM 
        employee e 
            INNER JOIN person p 
                ON e.person_id = p.id
    WHERE 
            e.membership_id = 1 
        AND e.type = 'INDIVIDUAL' 
        AND e.enabled = 1
    ORDER BY 
        p.first_name ASC, 
        p.last_name ASC, 
        p.id ASC
    LIMIT 
        100;
```

Comment: Sure that you are answering the right question? You might need to read it again. An index covering the ORDER BY clause is esseintial for the performance of this query.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, I do understand that, but his sample data scenario only ever populated all membership ID = 1 and INDIVIDUAL and enabled.  It would always be returning ALL records regardless and is only coincidentally giving the user correct answers.  The critical consideration is that the where to filter would still need to return a possible 200k records.  What if it is record 199,999 that the first name is "Aadam" and is now the front of the list, but was the last qualified record of the WHERE clause... or anywhere in between the data.  That is my concern they may not have explicitly expressed.

Comment: @DRapp I tried your suggestions, and it improved the query performance by about 10-15%.  I think I'm going to go with native SQL for now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ScottVanWart, I think the real issue you have is that no matter what your order by..  See my clarification message to Paul two comments above on why I think the performance issue.

Comment: @DRapp I definitely think the data is skewed out of favour of the stuff I'm filtering by. In terms of number of rows, the WHERE clause does nothing helpful and the example itself is largely contrived. I think the long-term solution is going to be to keep the relevant data together even if that means duplicating columns from one table in another.

Answer (score 0):

Storing first and last names redundantly in the `employee` table is an option - But with drawbacks. You will have to manage the redundancy. To guarantee the consistency, you can make those columns part of the foreign key. `ON UPDATE CASCADE` will take you some work. But you will still need to rewrite your INSERT statements or use triggers. With `first_name` and `last_name` being part of the `employee` table, you would be able to create an optimal index for your query. The table would look the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    membership_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(15),
    enabled BIT NOT NULL,
    person_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES person ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_employee_membership_id FOREIGN KEY ( membership_id ) REFERENCES membership ( id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_employee_person FOREIGN KEY ( person_id, first_name, last_name ) 
                                  REFERENCES person ( id, first_name, last_name ),
    INDEX (membership_id, type, enabled, first_name, last_name, person_id)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

The query would change to:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
WHERE e.membership_id = 1 AND e.type = 'INDIVIDUAL' AND e.enabled = 1
ORDER BY e.first_name ASC, e.last_name ASC, e.person_id ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

However - I would avoid such changes if possible. There might be other ways to use an index for ORDER BY. I would first try to move the WHERE conditions into a correlated EXISTS subquery:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM person p INNER JOIN employee e ON p.id = e.person_id
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM employee e1
  WHERE e1.person_id = p.id
    AND e1.membership_id = 1
    AND e1.type = 'INDIVIDUAL'
    AND e1.enabled = 1
)
ORDER BY p.first_name ASC, p.last_name ASC, p.id ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

Now, to evaluate the subquery, the engine needs `p.id`, so it has to start reading the data from `person` table first (which you will see in the execution plan). And I guess it will be smart enough to read it from the index. Note that in *InnoDB* the primary key is always part of any secondary key. So the `idx_person_first_name_last_name` index is actually on `(first_name, last_name, id)`.